# Find duplicate audio files via meta-tags?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command-line

I had Banshee's meta-data fixer handle all the meta-data inconsistency, now does anyone know some command line fu to search recursively through a directory and find duplicate files based on similar meta-data in regard to song title, artist name and finally, print a list of the file names of the duplicates?

I'm trying to remove many redundant **audio** files and I've found a program called dupeGuru to be somewhat helpful, but I'd like to simply print out a list of the duplicate filenames like:

```
/home/username/Music/song.mp3
/home/username/Music/oldItunes/song.wma
```

and then finally redirect this output to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `exiftool`.

To get `comment` tag of all `*.{jpg,png}` files in `/path/to/dir/`:

```
$ exiftool -r -ext .jpg -ext .png -comment /path/to/dir/
```

Comment: Can using exiftool be use for audio files in any significant way?  It appears it's for images only.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I'll play around with this and see what I come up with.